# Add new document to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

So I'm new to MongoDB and is doing some learning on FreeCodeCamp. There is a task where I need to insert a document to database, **I successfully completed the task**, but the document doesn't seem to reach the database (I've checked it in MongoDB Compass). Here is the code I've wrote:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

let personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  age: Number,
  favoriteFoods: [String]
}) // making schema for person

let Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema) // defining schema model for Person

const createAndSavePerson = (done) => {
  var rickSanchez = new Person({
    name: 'Rick',
    age: 22,
    favoriteFoods: ['Ice Cream', 'Nasi Kebuli']
  }) // making new document from a model

  rickSanchez.save(function(err, data) { // saving the document
    if (err) return console.error(err)
    done(null, data); // passing the document data to callback
  })
};
```

I tried to call the function, but I got confused because there's a callback function as parameter, I tried to pass `done()` while calling it but it gets an error. What should I do so my document (*rickSanchez*) inside the function is being sent to MongoDB?

Any helpful answer would be very appreciated!

Comment: What is the error and where is `createAndSavePerson` called?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor There is no error, I've passed the challenge. But there is no document that is being sent to my MongoDB. I'm confused on how to call the ```createAndSavePerson``` function since it has a callback function as parameter. How to call it?